# SQL: how to get a unique random number with no collision in a UDF

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find a definitive way to calculate a random and unique key in SQL (using SQL 2012).

I have a table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Variables
(
   ...
   KeyId bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT(dbo.GetKeyId())
)
```

with UDF defined like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetKeyId]()
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @maxAttempts INT = 100
    DECLARE @MaxID bigint
    DECLARE @NewKeyId bigint

    SET @MaxID = POWER(36.0, 12)

    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT FLOOR((SELECT rndvalue FROM rnd)*@MaxID) AS rn, 1 AS i

        UNION ALL

        SELECT FLOOR((SELECT rndvalue FROM rnd)*@MaxID) AS rn, i = i + 1
        FROM CTE AS c
            INNER JOIN Variables AS r ON c.rn = r.KeyId
        WHERE (i < @maxAttempts)
           AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Variables WHERE KeyId=c.rn)
    )
    SELECT TOP 1 @NewKeyId = rn
    FROM CTE
    ORDER BY i DESC

    RETURN @NewKeyId
END
```

And of course the following view

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[rnd]
AS
    SELECT RAND() AS rndvalue
```

After testing this solution on a small scale I see that it does not work. Sometimes it returns a key value that already exists. Using UDF gives me a lot of headaches with restrictions.
Can anyone suggest a version that works?

Comment: Why don't you just use `IDENTITY`?

Comment: I am using an identity key but, for this KeyId field, I want the value to be random.

Comment: @pdube Test it with `IF Exists` before get the value from the fonction

Comment: `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` data type would give you a random value.

Comment: With your `UDF`, you might run into concurrency issues as well.

Comment: stop trying to do this manually. @WEI_DBA has given you two perfect suggestions :)

Comment: I need a bigint and not UNIQUEIDENTIFIER unfortunately...

Comment: What you ask for is fundamentally impossible. "Random except not any value already in the table" is a complicated way of saying "not random" so any function designed to generate a random number will fail for your purposes. What you *want* probably isn't a random number. What properties are you looking for in the generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of classic approaches:

- fill in table/array with lots of random values
- number the rows in it with identity/index
- refer it's rows with independently secuentially incremented value

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE BulkOfRealRandoms (id int identity(1,1), rand_value BINARY(8)
```

Fill it with something like db of md5's. I mean do this as one-time job. Don't do anytnihg like this in OLTP scenarios, inside transactions. As many other said - your udf is a performance killer.

```
CREATE TABLE RandomReceiver (self_id int, rand_value_id int)
```

You may use IDENTITY or SEQUENCE to generate `rand_value_id`. That's how you'll get *random values with no collusions* fast and confidently enough.

If you are trying to hide growth of some tables in your db with assigning random public ids instead of sequential ones, then you should probably invent an algorythm for producing such ids which probably might be of string datatype. Qualitative randomization is not a trivial task. And if this is your scenario (producing of public order ids or similar) then random numbers won't be really comfortable and useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recomand to use `IDENTITY` or `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, but if you insist to do it like that, try this:

1- Create your function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetKeyId ()
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Value BIGINT;
    ExixtsValue:
    SET @Value = (CONVERT(BigInt, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3)) % 1000000);
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyVariables WHERE KeyId = @Value)
        GOTO ExixtsValue;
RETURN @Value
END
```

2- Create test table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyVariables (
    KeyId bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT(dbo.GetKeyId())
);
```

3- Test it as many you want:

```
INSERT INTO MyVariables VALUES (dbo.GetKeyId() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Sami's answer would not be too bad if CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM could be used in a UDF.

My final solution is to not use a UDF for the default value of KeyId. Then, keys are pre-generated in a table and the KeyId value is extracted at the time of insertion into Variables table (in a SP doing the insertion).

So the Variables table is defined like:

```
CREATE TABLE Variables
(
   ...
   KeyId bigint NOT NULL
)
```

and the PoolKeys table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PoolKeys](
    [KeyId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Rank] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

I defined this view to get a big random number (OK pseudo-random):

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[rndBig]
AS
    SELECT ABS(CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(10) AS bigint)) AS rndvalue
```

Then this SP to generate new keys:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GenerateNewKeys]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @min int = 1
    DECLARE @max bigint = POWER(36.0, 12)-1     -- needs to be an odd value
    DECLARE @n INT = 1000

        ;WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT TOP(@n) CONVERT(bigint, FLOOR((SELECT rndvalue FROM dbo.rndBig) * CONVERT(float, (@max - @min + 1) / @max))) % @max + @min AS KeyId,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]) AS rnk
        FROM sys.all_objects as s1 
            CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects as s2
    )
    INSERT INTO PoolKeys(KeyId, [Rank])
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@n) s.KeyId, s.rnk
    FROM CTE AS s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Variables V WHERE V.KeyId = s.KeyId)
END
```

And the SP to extract a new KeyId:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNewKey]
(
    @KeyId bigint output
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM PoolKeys)
    BEGIN
        EXEC GenerateNewKeys
    END

    DECLARE @res TABLE(KeyId bigint);

    ;WITH T AS
        (SELECT TOP(1) *
            FROM PoolKeys
            ORDER BY [Rank]
        )
    DELETE FROM T
    OUTPUT deleted.KeyId INTO @res

    SELECT TOP (1) @KeyId=KeyId FROM @res
END
```

With all this in place, in the SP doing INSERT INTO Variables, I call GetNewKey to get the next KeyId which I insert into Variables.
So once every 1000 calls a few milliseconds will be spent generating another 1000 keys. This is acceptable in my case.